# Alias "ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget" is invalid error in yii highchart

Tags: php, yii, highcharts

I just downloaded the highchart extension from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/highcharts/) and followed the instruction which says that extract and copy the file inside protected/extension. Also I have put the code:

```
'options' => array(
      'title' => array('text' => 'Fruit Consumption'),
      'xAxis' => array(
         'categories' => array('Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges')
      ),
      'yAxis' => array(
         'title' => array('text' => 'Fruit eaten')
      ),
      'series' => array(
         array('name' => 'Jane', 'data' => array(1, 0, 4)),
         array('name' => 'John', 'data' => array(5, 7, 3))
      )
   )
));
```

inside my view. But when I try to access this view it gives me error saying:

> Alias ext.highcharts.HighchartsWidget is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable

Can any one please help me where else I need to give the entry for this extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read about extensions in yii and solved the problem,those who wants fix for this can follow the link,I have answered it in yii forum

[here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/69412-setup-for-highcharts-extension/page__gopid__294866#entry294866)

Comment: It is also important to double check the folder structure. In this case, the assets folder and php classes should be direct children of the highcharts folder you are placing right under protected/extensions.